# Перенос строки в выводимым php скриптом alert

Tags: php, javascript

Есть скрипт. При регистрации он выводит алерт с причиной которая появляется из PHP скрипта, но если причин сразу несколько, то надо делать перенос строки, html тэги не работают, пробывал выводить \n\r, тоже не работает. Видимо надо как-то в самом скрипте прописывать.

```js
function register()
{
   if(document.getElementById("five").checked) {
   document.getElementById('reg').disabled = true;
   var nick = document.getElementById("one").value;
   var pass = document.getElementById("two").value;
   var secretik = document.getElementById("three").value;
   var rules = document.getElementById("five").value;
    $.post("index.php?engine=reg_post",{login:nick,password:pass,secret:secretik,rule:rules} , function(data) {
   alert (data);
   document.getElementById('reg').disabled = false;
    });
   }
   else
   {
   alert('Вы не согласились с правилами!');
   document.getElementById('reg').disabled = false;
   }
}
```

Comment: а вы посмотрите что вам приходит в ответе, там может обрезаются все переносы? вообще, `\n` вроде нормально должно отработать. "Посмотреть" можно в консоли браузера на вкладке "Сеть"/"Network" (или похожей)

Comment: http://rghost.ru/6yshgtXxS/image.png
view-source:http://world.s56.wh1.su/?engine=reg_post
Все вроде правильно.

Comment: видно jquery сам символы экранирует. Под рукой нет, проверить сам не могу (местный редактор не может отправить запрос на ваш сайт из-за Access-Control-Allow-Origin), попробуйте [dataType](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) передать, там можно указать `html`, тогда вроде и теги заработают.

Comment: насколько помню, в php \n надо писать в в двойных кавычках, чтобы воспринимался символ переноса. Возможно в этом проблема.

Answer (score 1):

Решил не париться с алертом, сделал просто вывод в блоке.

```js
function register() {
  if (document.getElementById("five").checked) {
    document.getElementById('reg').disabled = true;
    var nick = document.getElementById("one").value;
    var pass = document.getElementById("two").value;
    var secretik = document.getElementById("three").value;
    var rules = document.getElementById("five").value;
    $.post("index.php?engine=reg_post", {
      login: nick,
      password: pass,
      secret: secretik,
      rule: rules
    }, function(data) {
      document.getElementById('errorregister').innerHTML = data;
      document.getElementById('reg').disabled = false;
    });
  } else {
    alert('Вы не согласились с правилами!');
    document.getElementById('reg').disabled = false;
  }
}
```